# Socket.io on port 443

Tags: node.js, sockets, iis, websocket, socket.io

I have a little problem when I'm trying to load socket server on port 443 with node.js

The port is taken by IIS.

All my customers can use only port 443 to connect to my socket.

In my IIS I have 4 IP addresses.
I try to config the socket.io to use one of the IP's that are not configure in the IIs. But it didn't work.

Do I have any solution to use port 443 in socket server and also use it in IIS?

Thank you

Comment: Not at the same time, no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS: Websocket and IIS sharing port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071948/iis-websocket-and-iis-sharing-port-443)

Comment: Configure IIS as a proxy to direct incoming socket.io requests to your server?  Or put a proxy in front of IIS to direct socket.io requests to your server and let the rest go through to IIS.  Or, use a different host, different hostname and different IP address for your 443 server.

Comment: Let your node server run at another port, and then use IIS as reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing